# Matlab optimization, failure in initial objective function evaluation

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I want to solve an optimization problem by Matlab `fmincon` function. I defined my objective function as:

```
function f = objfun(x,p1,p2)
x1=x(1:24);
y1=x(25:48);
z1=x(48:end);

f=-mean(x1*(p1)'+y1*(p2)')+mean(z1*(p1)')
end
```

`p1`,`p2` are 1x24 vectors which are calculated in the main file. I need to find the optimum values for `x1`, `y1` and `z1` which are 1x24 vectors (total 72 variables).

When I run the main code I get an error message about the objective function and then for `fmincon` caused by failure in initial objective function evaluation.

Would you please advise how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You should also show us the error message

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How do you call `fmincon`?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `x` is a 1x72 vector, I think there is a typo on the line 4 of your code.

```
z1=x(48:end);
```

This will give you a **1x25** vector and the latter multiplication `z1*(p1)'` will not work since `p1` is 1x24.

I suppose you mean:

```
z1=x(49:end);
```

This way you have the 24 last elements of x, and the multiplication `z1*(p1)'` is possible.